# Kerberos Spark (2.4.6) Jobs are getting Stuck not terminating on its own

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I'm Using Spark 2.4.6 in Kerberized environment. I'm Submit a spark batch job via shell script, where i'm passing principal and wrong keytab file, not performing Kinit operation. Though my spark job runs for 24 hours and keeps on running.

I'm launching 3 executors and can see one executor is active all the time, Upon checking the log it says :-

```
21/05/25 13:00:19 WARN AbstractRpcClient: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
21/05/25 13:00:19 ERROR AbstractRpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:737)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:734)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:734)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:856)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:32831)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner$SmallReversedScannerCallable.call(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner$SmallReversedScannerCallable.call(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:396)
```

I've Tried with Spark Speculative Mechanism and

**> spark.yarn.MaxAppAtempts=1**

but still no luck .
I want spark itself to kill the process , any lead on this is highly appreciable.

Speculation config which i tried :

```
config("spark.speculation", "true")
config("spark.speculation.interval", "10m")
config("spark.speculation.multiplier", "10")
config("spark.speculation.quantile", "0.10")
```